# SQLComplete:The dbext plugin must be loaded for dynamic SQL completion

Tags: plugin

I use vim 8.2.3458 without any SQL specific plug-ins. Whenever I try to edit a SQL file the following error message keeps popping up:

```
SQLComplete:The dbext plugin must be loaded for dynamic SQL completion
```

When this message shows the editor freezes for about two seconds, making the edition of SQL files a rather painful experience.

I thus experimented adding a pointer to the plugin at GitHub in the `.vimrc` file:

```
Bundle 'vim-scripts/dbext'
```

However, when I run `:PluginInstall` Vundle returns an authentication error trying to access the dbext repository.

How can I get rid of the `SQLComplete` error?

Comment: do not use the vim-scripts mirror. It contains old versions and is not updated anymore. Download the script manually from https://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=356 and unzip it into your `~/.vim/` folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to add `.vim` to the end of the plugin name. try:

```
Bundle 'vim-scripts/dbext.vim'
```